# SQL Pivot Query for data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ucQ.png)i currently have a report that uses the following query and produces the following results by row;

[image: query and results]

i would like the result to look like the following;

[image]

Comment: How are you intending to create the final table? Most reporting tools have pivot functionality built-in that's much cleaner and  more flexible than pivoting in SQL.

Comment: thank you for responding, i am able to create the result in report builder in ssrs but my boss wants to see if i can create a query using the "pivot" feature, not sure how well it gonna work though.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how comfortable you are pushing back but I'd want to understand _why_ your boss wants to use PIVOT. I'd show some examples of PIVOT to show that it's much more cumbersome and less flexible (you have to define the column upfront or use even uglier dynamic SQL). What benefit does your boss expect from using PIVOT, or is just an experimental/learning exercise?

Comment: If this is not some kind of experiment, you should reserve SQL pivot functions for datasets that are too large for Excel to pivot.

Comment: i created a pivot and got the following result and i have already created the report in SSRS but i would like to know how to actually do it in sql..i figured out how to pivot but i guess i need one more query to pivot on the [Day] to get it to look like the example in excel?...thanks